# Simple 'Def and If' in exam that i could not figure out

Tags: function, if-statement

This question came out in my Python exam and I could not answer it.

```
x = 7
y = 3
def a(x):
    return b(x)
def b(y):
    if y == 6:
        return x - y
    return a(x-1)
print(a(4))
```

The answer is 1. 
But I'm not sure how it is derived.

Hope someone can give me a clear explanation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The calling procedure is:

```
a(4)
b(4)
a(6)
b(6)  # returns 7 - 6 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If we remove the noise from the code:

```
def a(x):
    return b(x)
```

Function `a` is just an alias for `b`, we can remove `a` completely:

```
x = 7
y = 3
def b(y):
    if y == 6:
        return x - y
    return b(x - 1)
print(b(4))
```

Let's rename parameters to properly distinguish between variables and function parameters:

```
x = 7
y = 3
def b(paramY):
    if paramY == 6:
        return x - paramY
    return b(x - 1)
print(b(4))
```

or

```
def b(paramY):
    if paramY == 6:
        return 7 - paramY
    return b(7 - 1)
print(b(4))
```

or

```
def b(paramY):
    if paramY == 6:
        return 7 - paramY
    return b(6)
print(b(4))
```

Now, if you notice the function:

- if `paramY` is `6`, it will return `7 - paramY`, that is, `7 - 6`, that is `1`.
- if `paramY` is not `6`, it will return `b(6)`, that is, it will also return `1`.

It doesn't matter what you pass to function `b`, it will always return `1`.